# angular-tour-of-heroes gives 404 for 'api/heroes"

Tags: angular, angular-tour-of-heroes

Just started learning angular development. Following official angular doc from angular.io.
Everything was working fine step by step till I reach https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6

Added HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule for mocking remote server, now it's not working.

here is browser console logs: [image]

It's now able to find out 'api/heroes' endpoint. this may be configuration issue with 'HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule'.

Here is my source code: https://github.com/csankhala/angular-tour-of-heroes

Please let me know what I missed?

Comment: try to change HEROES to heroes inside your in-memory-data.service

Comment: oh my god. it works. Thanks a lot. 
but i didn't understand, it is just a local variable. how it is mapped to endpoint url?

Comment: it's the way the in memory module map your data to url so you don't have to configure it yourself as its goal is to help you to prototype quickly (not production friendly)

Comment: Thanks. As your solution works, you can post it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your urls must matchs the name of your data declared inside the `in-memory-data.service`.

In this situation, in order to query `api/heroes`, the *createDb()* function returned object must include a variable named `heroes` (rather than `HEROES`).

Comment: i had the same problem but my variable was correctly named heroes. my problem was i had "return heroes;" instead of "return {heroes};" in the createDb() function. just adding this here in case of anyone having the same problem as me